# Python rrdtool.OperationalError: invalid x-grid format

Tags: python, rrdtool

The code of graph.py is :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
import rrdtool
import time
```

#
Define the headline above the chart

```
title="Server network traffic flow ("+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d',time.localtime(time.time()))+")"
```

#
Generate a Flow.png file

```
rrdtool.graph("Flow.png", "--start", "-1d", "--vertical-label=Bytes/s",\
"--x-grid", "MINUTE:12:HOUR:1:0:%H",\
"--width", "650", "--height", "230", "--title", title,
"DEF:inoctets=Flow.rrd:eth0_in:AVERAGE",      #Specify the NIC inflow data source DS and CF 
"DEF:outoctets=Flow.rrd:eth0_out:AVERAGE",    #Specify the network card outgoing traffic data source DS and CF
"CDEF:total=inoctets,outoctets,+",            #Combine the incoming and outgoing traffic through the CDEF to get the total traffic total

"LINE1:total#FF8833:Total traffic",           #Draw total flow in lines
"AREA:inoctets#00FF00:In traffic",            #Draw inflow in area
"LINE1:outoctets#0000FF:Out traffic",         #Draw outflow in lines
"HRULE:6144#FF0000:Alarm value\\r",           #Draw a horizontal line as an alarm line with a threshold of 6.1K
"CDEF:inbits=inoctets,8,*",                   #Convert incoming traffic to bit, ie *8, calculate the result to inbits
"CDEF:outbits=outoctets,8,*",                 #Convert the outgoing traffic to bit, ie *8, and calculate the result to outbits
"COMMENT:\\r",                                #Output a line break below the grid
"COMMENT:\\r",
"GPRINT:inbits:AVERAGE:Avg In traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps",  #Draw inflow average
"COMMENT:   ",
"GPRINT:inbits:MAX:Max In traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps",      #Draw inflow maximum
"COMMENT:   ",
"GPRINT:inbits:MIN:MIN In traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps\\r",   #Draw inflow minimum
"COMMENT:   ",
"GPRINT:outbits:AVERAGE:Avg Out traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps", #Draw outflow average
"COMMENT:   ",
"GPRINT:outbits:MAX:Max Out traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps",    #Draw outflow maximum
"COMMENT:   ",
"GPRINT:outbits:MIN:MIN Out traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps\\r")  #Draw outflow minimum
```

When I execute " python graph.py "

The error report :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "graph.py", line 31, in

```
"GPRINT:outbits:MIN:MIN Out traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps\\r")
```

rrdtool.OperationalError: invalid x-grid format

How can I slove this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

`rrdtool.OperationalError: invalid x-grid format`

From the [RRDTool Manual](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html):

> **X-Axis**
>
> [-x|--x-grid GTM:GST:MTM:MST:LTM:LST:LPR:LFM]
>
> The x-axis label is quite complex to configure. If you don't have very
>   special needs it is probably best to rely on the auto configuration to
>   get this right. You can specify the string none to suppress the grid
>   and labels altogether.
>
> The grid is defined by specifying a certain amount of time in the ?TM
>   positions. You can choose from SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH
>   or YEAR. Then you define how many of these should pass between each
>   line or label. This pair (?TM:?ST) needs to be specified for the base
>   grid (G??), the major grid (M??) and the labels (L??). For the labels
>   you also must define a precision in LPR and a strftime format string
>   in LFM. LPR defines where each label will be placed. If it is zero,
>   the label will be placed right under the corresponding line (useful
>   for hours, dates etcetera). If you specify a number of seconds here
>   the label is centered on this interval (useful for Monday, January
>   etcetera).

As you can see, your x-grid option is too short as you have omitted the labelling intervals:

`"--x-grid", "MINUTE:12:HOUR:1:0:%H",`

Try this instead, which labels every 4h:

`"--x-grid", "MINUTE:12:HOUR:1:HOUR:4:0:%H`

Comment: When I  Try this instead, which labels every 4h:


"--x-grid", "MINUTE:12:HOUR:1:HOUR:4:0:%H"


Then I execute " python graph.py " .


It report error :


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "graph.py", line 31, in <module>

    "GPRINT:outbits:MIN:MIN Out traffic\: %6.21f %Sbps\\r")

rrdtool.OperationalError: bad format for GPRINT in 'Avg In traffic: %6.21f %sbps' .

How can I slove this problem ?

Comment: That is  separate error, and looks like you have `%6.21f` where you probably meant to have `%6.2lf`.  It is an error in the GRPRINT format string, as the error states.